# DevicePolicyManager. setMaximumTimeToLock setting value to "Immediately"

Tags: android

I am trying to set Maximum Time Lock using DevicePolicyManager, but it is not working with any value it set "Lock automatically" value as "Immediately" without any other option on device.
As per API doc it says it accepts time in mili-sec. But API not accepting reflecting it at device, it changes to "immediately" option and while sending 0 it reset value to default which was set earlier by user.

Please let me know what is expected value here, I have tried so many values in sec, milisec, but nothing working. Tested same on 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 but the behavior is same.

Thank you,
Regards,
Aparna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason, Lock Automatically property works with Display screen timeout. API sets value to immediately for "auto-lock" property and whatever value set for lock goes to "screen timeout"